# How to draw coloured Lines and polygons using Directx11 without fx file?

Tags: directx-11

I need to draw a set of lines using a given colour. I have seen many samples that uses pixel shader and fx files. My requirement is bit simpler. I need to draw a set of lines (LineStrip) using a given vertices by a provided colour. I don't want to use any pixel shader mechanisms of a fx file. In Direct3D9 I have a Line object and I was well managed to implement it. But when I moved to Direct3D11 I am trapped. Kindly please tell me how to draw lines, rectangles and Polygons (filled with colour). I tried with VertexPositionColor but couldn't succeed. Please help!!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably, my recent answer here may be of help: [How to draw line and font without D3DX9 in DirectX 9?] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720882/how-to-draw-line-and-font-without-d3dx9-in-directx-9/20728720#20728720). Principles for D3D9 and D3D11 are the same, and I list some helper libs there also.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed pipeline does not exist anymore with DX11. You have to use a vertex and a pixel shader.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do this with a small code snippet ( I mean to say without using a fx file). Also is there any option to set the Thickness of a line and set line features (like dotted lines)? Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to emulate thickness and stipple with geometry shader. Here a forum thread about how to do the thickness : https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/smooth-thick-lines-using-geometry-shader